# parallel computations on Reference Classes

Tags: r, parallel-processing, reference-class

I have a list of fairly large objects that I want to apply a complicated function to in parallel, but my current method uses too much memory.  I thought Reference Classes might help, but using `mcapply` to modify them doesn't seem to work.

The function modifies the object itself, so I overwrite the original object with the new one.  Since the object is a list and I'm only modifying a small part of it, I was hoping that R's copy-on-modify semantics would avoid having multiple copies made; however, in running it, it doesn't seem to be the case for what I'm doing.  Here's a small example of the base R methods I have been using.  It correctly resets the balance to zero.

```
## make a list of accounts, each with a balance
## and a function to reset the balance
foo <- lapply(1:5, function(x) list(balance=x))
reset1 <- function(x) {x$balance <- 0; x}
foo[[4]]$balance
## 4 ## BEFORE reset
foo <- mclapply(foo, reset1)
foo[[4]]$balance
## 0 ## AFTER reset
```

It seems that using Reference Classes might help as they are mutable, and when using `lapply` it does do as I expect; the balance is reset to zero.

```
Account <- setRefClass("Account", fields=list(balance="numeric"),
                       methods=list(reset=function() {balance <<- 0}))

foo <- lapply(1:5, function(x) Account$new(balance=x))
foo[[4]]$balance
## 4
invisible(lapply(foo, function(x) x$reset()))
foo[[4]]$balance
## 0
```

But when I use `mclapply`, it doesn't properly reset.  Note that if you're on Windows or have `mc.cores=1`, `lapply` will be called instead.

```
foo <- lapply(1:5, function(x) Account$new(balance=x))
foo[[4]]$balance
## 4
invisible(mclapply(foo, function(x) x$reset()))
foo[[4]]$balance
## 4
```

What's going on?  How can I work with Reference Classes in parallel?  Is there a better way altogether to avoid unnecessary copying of objects?

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior. it resets well for me with `mclapply`( I get 0 balance) . Do you I need to init core numbers before?

Comment: Well that's interesting, @agstudy.  I tried it again here and the same things happens.  What do you mean by your second sentences?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: @agstudy, I wonder if you're on Windows, where `lapply` is simply called instead.  Updated question to reflect.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13942202/210673

Answer (score 2):

I think the forked processes, while they have access to all the variables in the workspace, must not be able to change them.  This works, but I don't know yet if it improves the memory issues or not.

```
foo <- mclapply(foo, function(x) {x$reset(); x})
foo[[4]]$balance
## 0
```